# rails edit_model_name_url(@model_name) does not take me to edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to redirect to edit page on dropdown change event from new page.
   if data is present in database for selected week then display that data in 
   edit page.
   for this i use ajax method .
   this is working perfectly

```
 $('select#weeknumber').on('change', function(event) {
  var selected_id= $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/clients/changeweek/',
     data:{ week: selected_id}       

});
```

});

Inside my controller i have a changeweek method from which i want to 
  redirect to edit page with specific id.For this i used redirect_to which 
  creates the link which i want but the edit page did not load it still remains 
  on new.html.erb

```
def changeweek 
@weekcheck = Client.where('weeknumber = ?',params[:week])

   if @weekcheck.nil?
    @clientdata = Client.new(params[:weeknumber] => params[:week])
    redirect_to new_client_path(@client)
    else
    @client = Client.find_by('weeknumber = ?',params[:week])
    redirect_to edit_client_url(@client)
    end

end
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't do that as call is `ajax`

You need to replace redirect_to with,

```
render :js => "window.location = '#{new_client_path(@client)}'"
```

Other way you can do redirect in `$.ajax` `success` method